Upper and lower bounding singular values of a nearly orthogonal matrix
Let $u_1, \dots, u_n$ be $n$-dimensional unit vectors and let $U = \begin{bmatrix}u_1 & \dots & u_n \end{bmatrix}$ be a matrix formed by stacking these vectors columnwise.
If $u_i^\top u_j = 0$ for all vectors indexed by $i \neq j$, then $U$ is an orthogonal matrix.
But what if we instead have a weaker condition that $-\epsilon \leq u_i^\top u_j \leq \epsilon$ for all $i \neq j$, where $\epsilon$ is a very small positive number close to zero? In this case, can I upper and lower bound the singular values to within a range of $1 \pm C \epsilon$ for some constant $C$?

A sketch of one idea - let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix formed by Gram–Schmidt on the sequence of vectors $u_1, \dots, u_n$. Then one could maybe show that $\Vert Q - U \Vert_F$ is small and then apply Weyl's inequality to show that the singular values of $U$ do not deviate much from one.

Another idea would be to try to lower bound $\text{Tr}[U Q] \geq c$ subject to the constraint that $Q$ is orthogonal. This would yield an upper bound $\Vert Q - U \Vert_F^2 \leq 2n - 2c$, so if $c$ is sufficiently close to $n$ we could again apply Weyl's inequality to obtain bounds on the largest and smallest singular value.

The largest singular value of $U$ is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $U^\top U$, which is $\lambda = \max ~ v^\top U^\top U v$ subject to $v$ being a unit vector. An upper bound on $\lambda \leq 1 + (\epsilon (n-1))/2$ is obtained by setting $U^\top U = (1 - \epsilon) I + \epsilon \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^\top$ and $v = (1/\sqrt{n}) \mathbf{1}$.

Sorry I think I did that calculation too fast in the previous comment. I think the upper bound should be $\lambda \leq 1 + \epsilon(n -1)$ and thus the largest singular value of $U$ is upper bounded by $\sqrt{1 + \epsilon(n -1)}$.

Let $U^\top U = I + M$ where $M$ is a matrix with zeros along the diagonal and $-\epsilon \leq M_{ij} \leq \epsilon$ for all off diagonal entries. The eigenvalues of $U^\top U$ are the squared singular values of $U$, so by upper and lower bounding the eigenvalues of $U^\top U$ we obtain the desired bounds on the singular values of $U$.
A bound on the largest eigenvalue is found by upper bounding $v^\top U^\top U v$ for any unit vector $v$.
$$v^\top U^\top U v = 1 + v^\top M v = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} M_{ij} v_i v_j \leq 1 + \epsilon \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} v_i v_j \leq 1 + \epsilon \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \epsilon (n - 1)$$
Where in the final inequality we set $v_i = 1 / \sqrt{n}$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$, which achieves the maximum attainable value.
An essentially identical argument can be used to lower bound the smallest eigenvalue (choosing $M_{ij} = -\epsilon$):
$$v^\top U^\top U v \geq 1 - \epsilon (n - 1)$$
We can attain these upper and lower bounds explicitly by setting:
$$U_{ij} = \sqrt{1 \pm \epsilon} \quad \text{if}~i = j \qquad \text{and} \qquad U_{ij} = \pm\sqrt{\epsilon/(n-1)} \quad \text{if}~i \neq j$$
In conclusion, the singular values $\sigma_1(U), \dots, \sigma_n(U)$ satisfy:
$$1 - \epsilon(n-1) \leq \sigma_n(U) \leq \dots \leq \sigma_1(U) \leq 1 + \epsilon(n-1)$$
